# Nginx wildcard DNS, com www, sem www e com subdomínio

Tags: nginx

Eu tenho um servidor Ngnix com a seguinte configuração:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .dominio.com.br;
    root /home/dominio.com.br/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/dominio.com.br-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Eu configurei o em meu domínio os DNS da seguinte forma:

Registro tipo A com nome `@` apontando para o IP do meu servidor
Registro tipo `CNAME` com nome `www` apontando para `@`
Registro tipo `CNAME` com nome `*` apontando para `@`

[image: DNS]

Se eu entro usando o endereço `dominio.com.br` vai normal.
Se eu entro usando o endereço `www.dominio.com.br` ele redireciona para `dominio.com.br` sem o `www` (não quero que isso aconteça)
Se eu entro usando o endereço `qualquercoisa.dominio.com.br` ele acessa normal também sem redirecionar.

Se a pessoa entrar em qualquer um desses links informados acima tudo deve ser apontando para o mesmo aplicativo que esta na pasta `/home/dominio.com.br/public`

Se a pessoa entrar digitando somente dominio.com.br eu vou redirecionar para `www.dominio.com.br`

Por que o `www` está redirecionando para sem `www`? Podem me indicar onde estou errando ou o que estou deixando passar?

Answer (score 0):

creio que utilizando da forma a seguir pode solucionar seu problema.

```
server_name  *.example.org;
```

Comment: Não funcionou não

Comment: posta como ta seu dns para ficar mais facil

Comment: DNS adicionado na edição da minha pergunta.

Comment: desculpa mas imgs estão bloqueadas aqui na empresa não consigo visualizar ... quando chegar em casa tentarei te ajudar